# Pass a selected value to a second combo-box to filter available values

Tags: combobox, ms-access-2013

I am creating a form in Access 2013 which would allow the user to select a previously entered record for which they want to enter additional, related data. The underlying table has thousands of records so I want to use two combo boxes to make selection easier. According to multiple posts I’ve found elsewhere I should be able to set the Row Source of the cboGetSite combo-box to a table that lists all available sites. I then set the AfterUpdate() event to use the selected site to filter the second combo-box to a list that includes the available visits to that site with something like:

```
Private Sub cboGetSite_AfterUpdate()
    Me.cboGetDate.RowSource = “SELECT VisDate FROM” & _
                    “qrySiteVisits WHERE location =” & _
                    Me.cboGetSite & _
                    “ORDER BY VisDate”
End Sub
```

When I then select a value in the cboGetSite combo-box, I get an error that states,

“The expression After Update you entered as the event property setting produced the following error: Invalid outside procedure. *The expression may not result in the name of a macro, the name of a user-defined function, or [Event Procedure]. *There may have been an error evaluating the function, event, or macro.”

Can anyone suggest where I may be going wrong? I do not use VBA, so this is a stretch for me. I’m following guides found in several threads online. Please don’t respond with, “Well the error obviously tells you…” If it were obvious I wouldn’t be asking.

Can someone just walk me through the steps? Given a query that lists the available sites and dates of visits I need to:

1. Select a site from a combo-box thus setting a cboGetSite value
2. Pass cboGetSite to cboGetDate combo-box, thus filtering to a set of visit dates.
3. Select a date which sets a tempVar (with SetTempVar()) which is then set as the value in subsequent forms to add related data to one of several tables, linking it back to the correct Visit record via the cboGetDate variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your vba-code is painted red it is not valid!

After writing code use`Debug->Compile ...`in vba ide, this would show an syntax error!

From where did you copy that code? It uses wrong double-quotes (ASCII Char 147, 148 instead of 34 (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>))

After that you will receive another error because you're missing blanks in your sql-string `"SELECT VisDate FROM" &  "qrySiteVisits WHERE location ="` gets `"SELECT VisDate FROMqrySiteVisits WHERE location ="`. Missing a blank after FROM.

If`cboGetSite`and`location`are numbers this code will work.

```vb
Private Sub cboGetSite_AfterUpdate()
Dim SQL as String
SQL =  "SELECT VisDatem, id FROM " & _
                "qrySiteVisits WHERE location = " & _
                Me.cboGetSite & _
                " ORDER BY VisDate"
'If location and cboGetSite are strings use this: SQL =  "SELECT VisDate, id FROM " & _
                "qrySiteVisits WHERE location = '" & _
                Me.cboGetSite & _
                "' ORDER BY VisDate"
Debug.Print SQL ' shows the string in immidiate window in vba ide
Me.cboGetDate.RowSourceType = "Table/Query" 
Me.cboGetDate.RowSource = SQL
End Sub
```

What should happen if`cboGetDate`is selected first (`cboGetSite`is empty)? Show nothing, show all or move to `cboGetSite`?

Comment: I now get the list of locations to choose from, and no error when I select a location, but the cboGetDate list is empty. I note that cboGetSite is pulling from a site reference table, taking the numeric ID and string location fields, thus should be passing the num(ID) as the filter. I tried removing the ID and just passing the string field but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: To your other question, I'd actually prefer if cboGetDate is unavailable to select first. Too many dates to choose from, so they should have to select a site first.

Comment: So `location` is a number and `cboGetSite is a string? Then change the bound column in design-mode of `cboGetSite`control properties. if the control is bound, you have to change that field too. Don't pass the string because numbers are better. If it still fails, show the `Debug.Print`output and the recordsource of `cboGetSite`.

Comment: Interestingly I _thought_ I had tried the particular settings re: the bound column but evidently I didn't have something quite right. Appears to be working beautifully now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I did just realize one further piece I need to resolve. The VisDate value is selected from the qrySiteVisits query. I _also_ need to capture the qrySiteVisits.ID value, to set as a tempVar, which will then be the default value in a form that will open to add data related to that particular visit record. I had originally planned on just using a macro SetTempVar from the cboGetDate_AfterUpdate() field, but since the control is unbound, I'm not sure how to grab that value. Can you suggest how to set that?

Comment: Just add the desired field to the  `SELECT` (after the date as the combo is bound to first column). You can refence it with `cboGetDate.Column(1)`(1 as index is zero-based: first item is 0, second is 1, etc...).

Comment: I've tried several different variations and I can't get the TempVar to load as the value in the VisID field of the form I call up. Above, we used the SQL = SELECT... in the AfterUpdate event to pull the Visit ID. This is a number value corresponding to the tblVisits.ID key field. I then simply set TempVars!TempVisID = SQL. When I pull up a subsequent form I've tried setting the VisID value of the form as the TempVisID using a SetValue macro, and I've tried setting the default value on loading the form. Both still generate an error. Thoughts on where I'm going wrong? Seems simple.

Comment: Try `TempVars!TempVisID = Me.cboGetDate.Column(1)`.

Comment: I ran a query in AfterUpdate(). I thought one would call the values from the qry, but that doesn’t seem to work:
`REC = "SELECT Vis_Date_visNum, ID FROM " & _
            "qrySiteVisitDates WHERE Vis_Date_visNum = " & _
            Me.cboGetDate
            
Debug.Print REC 
TempVars!TempVisID = Me.cboGetDate.Column(1)
TempVars!TempOutingID = Me.cboGetDate.Column(0)`

If I look at the value, TempVisID shows NULL, while TempOutingID gets the value selected from the cboGetDate selection. No matter what I try I’m getting an error or NULL value for the ID, which should link my records.

Comment: Does anyone have any further suggestions to my problem? I'm afraid I'm getting to a point of having to ditch the thing and find some other method to link the records which I fear will introduce the potential for user error. e.g. if they have to pull the visit record of choice, and then type in the correct index on their own.

Comment: @A.Birdman: Is `ID`displayed in `cboGetDate` if you  make the second column  visible by adjusting `ColumnWidths`?

Comment: I am tentatively happy to say I've finally got it working. There was a `Row Source` value saved in `cboGetDate`. It appears that was 'blocking' the vba-based values from updating the field correctly, and thus the `ID` wasn't being registered and available for use in the VisID field of the forms. Removing the `RowSource` value and setting column widths to presumably show the ID (which it doesn't) seems to have resolved the issue! Now when I select a visit and open the next form, the values are filled in correctly. Thank you for your patience and assist.

Comment: Sorry, as I didn't use anything else than `RowSourceType = "Table/Query" ` I didn't  set it to. Updated my answer to prevent this error for others.